# Relationship between id and pid in ztree?

Tags: jquery, ztree

I'm new to ztree Jquery plugin.Kindly somebody help me to understand the relationship between id and pid with the below code.

```
var zNodes =[
    {id:1, pId:0, name:"[core] Basic Functions", open:true},
    {id:101, pId:1, name:"Standard JSON Data"},
    {id:102, pId:1, name:"Simple JSON Data"},
    {id:103, pId:1, name:"Don't Show Line"},
    {id:104, pId:1, name:"Don't Show Icon"},
    {id:105, pId:1, name:"Custom Icon - icon"},
    {id:106, pId:1, name:"Custom Icon - iconSkin"},
    {id:107, pId:1, name:"Custom Fonts"},

    {id:2, pId:0, name:"[excheck] Checkbox & Radio", open:false},
    {id:201, pId:2, name:"Checkbox Operation"},
    {id:202, pId:2, name:"Checkbox nocheck Demo"},
    {id:203, pId:2, name:"Checkbox chkDisabled Demo"}
    ]
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: pId is probably parent ID which link children to their parent node with this ID. What relationship you are meaning?

Comment: if you add next node with parent id 203, it will be hidden under node with this id

Comment: @daremachine I want to know why we numbering pId as 1,2,3.... and id as 100,101,200,201...?

Comment: if you look you can see ids 201,202,203 have parent id 2 which is parent node with id 2. So 201 etc... are children of parent node id 2, If you want to add third level of your tree you can add node with id 123456 but parent id 203 for example.

Comment: Now i understood the concept. Thanks @daremachine